# Link one value at the time of $scope.array to ngRepeat directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have simplified my code to this example to show what i want to accomplish.

**The controller:**

```
angular
   .module('myApp')
   .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function DashboardController($scope) {

$scope.someNumbers = [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' ];

}
```

**The View:**

```
<table class="table table.hover">
    <tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="num in someNumbers track by $index" all-numbers="someNumbers" dyn-rows></tr>
</table>
```

**The Directive:**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('dynRows', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<td>{{ allNumbers }}</td',
            scope: {
                allNumbers: "=",
            },
            link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
              // magic has to happen here?
            }
        }
    }
})
```

If i understand it well i now have 5 rows in my view, because of the `ng-repeat`, and 5 `models` in my directive. All 5 directive models have the `allNumbers` array.

What i want to accomplish is that for every new row i get ONE value out of the `someNumbers` array. `first row` the `first value` **(One)**, `second row`the `second value` **(Two)** and so on...

I think the magic has to happen inside of the directive `link` or inside the directive link () inside of my controllers view. After hours of searching and trying with loops and index playing i can't seem to find any information how to accomplish this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to generate rows with random numbers selected from an array provided. isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `all-numbers="someNumbers"` should be `all-numbers="num"` in order to get that index's value passed in instead of the whole array.

Comment: I just think i found how to do it after searching quiet some time... when i do `all-numbers="someNumbers[$index]"` it seems to send one value at the time. Is this an answer on my own question or is this the wrong way to do it? @Daniel Nalbach You gave me a step in this direction!

Comment: I guess you are trying to achieve this
<table class="table table.hover">
    <tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="num in someNumbers track by $index"><td>{{num}}</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: num should equal someNumbers[$index] and be available to any attribute on the ng-repeat element or any nested element

Comment: To clarify, num will not be an index position, it will be that index position's value as a standalone model.

Answer (score 0):

Well in answer to my own question and with the help of Daniel i have found the best solution for my problem.

As i have mentioned the above example was just a little example of my real code.

In my real code i have multiple arrays (with the same length). I wanted to send one value of every array each ngRepeat.

**Original line of code**

```
<tr class="dashboard-table-row" ng-repeat="labels in properLabels track by $index" dashboard-table all-labels="properLabels" all-years="properYears" all-data="properData"></tr>
```

**Changed to this**

```
<tr class="dashboard-table-row" ng-repeat="labels in properLabels track by $index" dashboard-table all-labels="{{properLabels[$index}}" all-years="properYears" all-data="{{properData[$index]}}"></tr>
```

adding the `[$index]` where i pass my array only sends the value equal to N index place in my array to my directive.

Hopes this helps people in the future!